# How to: Know "reachable" files for an user

Tags: document, user, accessibility

I'd like to know if in SP there's a method to know all the files "linked" to a user. This feature must be cross site collection and return all the files over the webapp that the user can read or contribute. That method had to work also with groups (if user A is in B group, and B group can read a Document Library, the function must return also all the files in B group)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest you can get with default functionality is to impersonate a user and make a search with the user whose "linked" files you're interested in listing.

Considering it is practically not possible to impersonate as each user, I would start off from this [blog article](http://blog.falchionconsulting.com/index.php/2010/04/discovering-who-has-access-to-sharepoint-2010-securable-objects/) and modify the code to be cross site collection and across all web apps.

You could then even schedule it to run during off-peak times and generate CSV or other listings per user.